# Should I go in work travel trip if I'm leaving the company soon?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, resignation, travel, company-norms

My company has decided to make a work travel trip  to celebrate opening their new office in another  country and to celebrate their success in the last year and share what plans they have in the future.

My company has invited me to come to the trip and invited some few more people but not everyone so they picked people who they mean to them the most to come to the trip.

I have been planning to leave the company due to reasons : career advancement and salary.
I had a positive interview and they informed they will send me the offer by next week or the week after (which might be delayed because of holidays in my country this week). My company travel trip is next week too.

I don’t have offer in my hand yet but I'm willing to leave once I get it and at the same time I might apologize for the trip and not get the offer

My relationship is good with my company and they are good with me. So, I don’t want to leave in a bad term.

Comment: why do you feel you shouldn't go? You don't even have another offer in hand yet, are you actively seeking a new job?

Comment: I’m  worried they will consider me not loyal or  don’t deserve the trip as i will leave them right after the trip if i took the offer

Comment: Why are you worried about what a company which doesn't value your career advancement or pay you appropriately thinks of you?

Comment: It’s just thay they are very good with me and told me before we want you to stay however they know I’m not satisfied with the salary and didn’t do anything about it . Also I don’t see any opportunity for career growth

Comment: "they are very good with me" "we want you to stay" "they know I’m not satisfied with the salary and didn’t do anything about it" Does not compute.

Answer (score 9):

You should go on the business trip, and continue to work at your current company as usual.

The reason is that you don't have the official offer letter yet.

When you wrote "**I don’t have the offer in my hand**", it practically means that you actually don't have the official offer letter yet.

---

There have been some very rare cases where some companies delay sending the official offer letters to job applicants, and then suddenly cancel the offers for various business reasons.

In addition, a reasonable boss at your current company would understand that you are not taking advantage of the company by going on the business trip while you don't have the official offer letter from the other company yet.

Comment: It’s not exactly a business trip since  they told us they want to celebrate it’s more of a party and not for a work purpose. If a i got the offer while I’m in the trip or few days after and then applied my resignation would i be considered not loyal or took advantage from them?

Comment: @lora90 see it this way: you got the "party" invitation because you are a valuable employee. So it's a reward for past performance. You don't take advantage of them if you attend.